# Apache VirtualHost is not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a server running Apache 2.4 on Windows, and I have set up a VirtualHost in the httpd-vhosts.conf file, and an 'A' record in my DNS server that points subdomain.mydomain.com to my IP address. Unfortunately, connecting to subdomain.mydomain.com just shows the same page as mydomain.com. Here is the code I used in the httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/subdomain/htdocs"
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "c:/Apache24/subdomain/logs/errors.log"
    CustomLog "c:/Apache24/subdomain/logs/access.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you added the `subdomain.mydomain.com` to your hosts file?

Comment: Belongs in Server Fault.

Comment: @Pankrates I'm not so clear as to what to add in the hosts file.

Comment: there is probably a line `127.0.0.1   localhost` make sure you add a line `127.0.0.1    subdomain.mydomain.com`

Comment: @Pankrates I have tried this, but it still didn't work. According to the Apache documentation, the hosts file needs to modified only for local access.

Comment: The rest of your configuration, or httpd.exe -S, is important. What other virtual hosts are present?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your domain provider configuration doesn't redirect @ to www, you need them to be configured separately to redirect to your machines IP address